# Should web service be separate from web site?

Tags: java, web-services, spring-mvc

I am building a website and also want to build a REST web service for accessing a lot of the same functionality (using google app engine and spring mvc3), and I'm not sure of the best practices for how integrated/separate the 2 parts should be.

For example if I want view a resource I can provide a url in the form:

```
{resourcetype}\{resourceid}
```

A GET request to this url can be redirected at a view which generates a webpage when the client is HTML/browser based.  Spring has (from what I read - not tried it yet) the ability to use this same resource URL to serve up a view which returns HTML/Xml/JSON depending on the content type.  This all seems great.

POST requests to a URL to create new resources in REST should return 201 CREATED (or so I read) along with the URL of the created resource, which seems fine for the Api but seems a little different from what would be expected from the norm in a web page (where you would likely be redirected to a page showing the resource you created or to a page saying it was created successfully or similar).  Should I handle this by serving up a page at a different URL which contains the form for creating the resource, then submits to the Api URL via ajax and gets the response and redirects to the resource URL included in the response.

This pattern seems like it would work (and should work for DELETE too) but is this a good approach or am I better keeping the REST Api URLs and the web site URLs separate?  this seems like it could introduce a fair bit of duplication and extra work.  But having a single URL could mean that you are dependent on javascript being available on the client of a HTML 5 supporting browser.

Comment: How big of a site are you thinking about? How many resource types?

Comment: not a huge number of resource types, in the order of 10 or so I'd say.  Probably quite a high volume of users, but all doing a few simple things

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I disagree with Michael's answer and use it as a basis for my own:

To "decouple your web urls from you API urls so they can each change indepentently." is to spit in the face of REST. [Cool URIs don't change](http://www.w3.org/Provider/Style/URI.html). Don't concern yourself with changing your URLs. Don't version your API *using URIs*. REST uses links to espouse the [OCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) -   a client operating on the previous version of your API should happily follow the links that existed when it went live, unknowing of new links that you've added to enhance your API.

If you insist on versioning your API, I'd ask that you do so using the media type, not the URI.

Next, " you simplify your implementation. Now every method doesn't have to determine if it's fronting JSON/XML or HTML."

If you're doing it this way, you're doing it wrong. Coming from Jersey, I return the same damn object from every method whether or not I produce HTML, XML or JSON. That's a completely cross-cutting concern that a marshaller takes care of. I use a VelocityMessageBodyWriter to emit HTML templates surrounding my REST representations.

Every resource in my system follows the same basic behavior:

```
class FooResource extends Resource {
    @GET
    public FooRepresentation get() {
        return new FooRepresentation();
    }
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
    public Response postForm(MulivaluedMap<String, String> form) {
        return post(buildRepresentationFromForm(form));
    }
    @POST
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Resopnse post(FooRepresentation representation) {
         // return ok, see other, whatever
    }
}
```

The GET method may need to build **Links** to other resources. These are used by consumers of a REST API as well as the HTML template. A form may have to POST and I use some particular Link (defined by the Relation) for the "action" attribute).

The path through the system may be different between a user-browser and a user-machine but **this is not a separation of implementation** - it *is* REST! The state transfer happens how it needs to, how you define it. How users (in a browser) proceed.

"Finally, by separating the site from the API, you allow for different scaling needs. If your API is getting hit hard but not the website, you can throw more hardware at the API while keeping the minimal needed for the website." - your scaling should not depend on who uses what here. Odds are you're doing some work behind the scenes that is more intense than just serving up HTML. By using the same implementation, scaling is even easier. The API itself (the marshaling between XML and domain objects and back) is not going to exceed the business logic and processing, database, etc.

Lastly, by keeping them the same, it is much easier to think about your system as a whole. In fact, start with the HTML. Define the relationships. If you're having a hard time expressing a particular action or user story in HTML anchors and forms, you're probably straying from REST.

Remember, you're expressing things as links (of a particular relation) to other things. Those URIs can even be different depending on whether you're producing XML or HTML - the HTML page might POST to URI some/uri/a and the API might POST to some/uri/b - that's irrelevant and being concerned with what the actual URI contents are is the dark path to POX and RPC

Another nifty feature is that if you do it this way, you're not dependent on JavaScript. You've defined your system to work with basic HTML and you can 'flip on' JavaScript when it is available. Then you're really working with your "API" anyway (I cringe at referring to them as different things, but I'm also trying to bridge my response in to your wording)

** I will add one final comment, when producing HTML, I use 303 instead of 201 in order to facilitate POST-then-GET. If JS is enabled, you're actually talking XML (or JSON) and you're back to 201.

Comment: Thanks Doug.  You example of a resource template was sort of how I was planning on things working.  There are a couple of things which are not clear to me from your answer though.  'A form may have to POST and I use some particular Link (defined by the Relation) for the "action" attribute' what do you mean by this.  Its not exactly clear to me.  Also how do you handle DELETE of resources when the client is a browser?  Does it have to have javascript to do this?

Comment: I actually quite agree with "Cool URLs don't change." For backwards compatibility you sometimes have to freeze a version of the API and (while still serving it up!) offer another version. A /v2/... path is a typical way of doing this.

Comment: Again, you can use the media type to convey that information. Different processing instructions for different media types.

Comment: Sam - to answer your question, I would have the DELETE handling in place for JavaScript and other clients, and I would probably have a separate resource that accepts POST with a URI specifying the resoure to be deleted. Again I ask, are you really sure you're DELETEing the resource? Or are you just flagging it with some invalid/inactive status? Do you want people to see "404" after it is deleted, or actually return something that says "Item delete by [user] on [date]". If the later, then you don't need DELETE. You can POST to the resource that kind of intent.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to try with this approach first, as this seems the most correct, and add in extra methods to make up shortcomings of non javascript clients if that is something I decide needs to be supported based on the browsers that visit the site.

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you keep them separate. By doing this you gain several benefits.

First, you decouple your web urls from you API urls so they can each change independently. For example, you may need to release backwards incompatible change to your API, in which case you can create a /v2/ directory. Meanwhile, you might want an /about page on the website but don't need one for your API.

By using different URLs, you simplify your implementation. Now every method doesn't have to determine if it's fronting JSON/XML or HTML. This is true even if you have a framework like Spring doing the heavy lifting; you still have do extra things for the website with respect to the current user.

It also eliminates a whole class of bugs. For example, users won't get JSON or XML output back while browsing the site—even if they have custom browser anonymity settings.

You can easily separate the logic for authentication. With a website, you need a login page and cookies. With an API, these aren't required but extra authentication headers are (for example, an HMAC+sha256 signature).

Finally, by separating the site from the API, you allow for different scaling needs. If your API is getting hit hard but not the website, you can throw more hardware at the API while keeping the minimal needed for the website.

---

**Update:**
To clarify, I'm not suggesting you code up everything twice. There are two different ways to look at this to remove duplication.

First, in MVC parlance, you have one model and two different views on that model. This is the whole point of MVC so that the view and model are not tied together. The code to get a particular resource is the same in both clients, so it you could write your model such that **only one line of code** gets that resource from the database or wherever it comes from. In short, your model is an easy-to-use library with two clients.

Another way to look at it is that your website is your very first client of your public REST API; the web server actually calls your RESTful API to gets it's information. This is the whole Eat Your Own Dog Food principle.

Comment: Thanks Michael, having changed URLs for different versions seems like a bad idea to me, and just because a URL exists, does the necessarily make it part of the API?  I think that using the same URLs would simplify the implementation, the returning of XML/JSON/HTML can be determined by the framework, I don't have to code something different for each.  If a new super format comes along that I want to support, I only have to wait for the framework to support it and bingo, nothing has to change. Using different urls for each returned type means I now have to add a new implementation (ctd..)

Comment: of every method that gets a resource.  I'm a bit taken by the bugs issue, that could indeed be a problem, but if someone is using custom settings that don't let you know they are a browser and want HTML then exactly who has the issue?  Me or them?  The authentication may also be an issue, I've not got as far as looking into that yet.  The scaling in my case is googles problem, as its running on App Engine, so that is moot.

Comment: By all means, on the API side, support XML/JSON/YAML/TheLatestCraze and switch between them there, but it doesn't really extend to fronting a website which is an entirely different beast than an API (see Will Hartang's discussion).

Comment: I suggest you do change URLs for different versions *when you make backwards incompatible changes* so you don't break existing clients. Additive changes to the API are fine to keep without changing version numbers. Also, don't remove the old API; this is the "Cool URLs Don't Change" principle mentioned by Doug.

Comment: I also tend to disagree with MVC as the basis for a REST service. I think of REST in RMR - Resource Method Representation. Your JavaScript client would have the notion of a Model, View and a Control. The model should be rich and talk REST to the Resource using Representations (of itself or other models).

Comment: @Doug I do not disagree with you about MVC; the principles are the same, just different execution. (I even prefer MVP over MVC in UI code) I merely wanted to use familiar terminology, and everyone and their dog knows MVC. The point was to make your model/resource code rich enough that you can use it easily in multiple places.

Answer (score 7):

In support of Michael, and in contrast to Doug, you should keep them separate.

Turns out that the browser, in its basic form, is not a particularly good REST client. Through lack of full support of HTTP, to lousy authentication support, to weak support for media types, the browser is actually quite limited. If you're limited to simply consuming content, and that content happens to be HTML, then the browser is fine, but going beyond that and the API suffers do to poor support in the browser.

JavaScript can improve the capability of the browser, and make it a better REST citizen, but few things work better in the browser than a static HTML page. Portable, performant, scaleable to different devices with some CSS fun. Everyone loves the snap of a static page, especially one that isn't hosting a zillion images and what not from other slow providers. Click, BANG, a fast appearing, fast scrolling page.

Since the browser is a sad citizen, you shouldn't limit your API to its weak capabilities. By separating them, you can write a nice, rich, animated, bouncy, exciting interface in HTML + JS, or Flash, or Java, Obj-C for iOS, or Android, or whatever.

You could also write a nice front end in PHP, hosted on your server, and pushing the results out to browser clients. The PHP app doesn't have to be REST at all, it can be just a generic web app, working in the domain and constraints of a web app (stateful sessions, non-semantic markup, etc. etc.). Browser talks to PHP, PHP talks to your REST service. The PHP app lets you segregate the demands of the browser from the semantics of a REST service.

You can write more RESTful HTML apps, even with pure HTML. They just turn out to be pretty crummy apps that folks don't like to use.

Obviously there is a lot of possible overlap between a generic web app and a REST service, but overlap is not equality, and they are different. HTTP != REST, using HTTP does not mean you're using REST. HTTP is well suited to REST applications, but you can certainly use HTTP in non-RESTful ways. People do it all day long.

So, if you want to use REST as a service layer, then do that. Leverage REST for REST sake, and build up your service. Then, start working on clients and interfaces that leverage that service. Don't let your initial client choice color the REST service itself. Focus on use cases of functionality, then build your clients around that.

As the needs of each component change, they can grow in congruence with or separately from each other as necessary. You don't have to punish the mobile apps for a change that a browser requires, or vice a versa. Let each piece be their own master.

Addenda:

Sam -

There's nothing wrong with offering a hybrid approach where some of the requests are served directly by your REST service layer while others are handled through a server side proxy. As long as the semantics are the same, it doesn't really matter. Your REST service certainly doesn't care. But it does potentially become problematic if the REST service returns link rels that are specific to the "raw" REST service rather than the hybrid. Now you have an issue of translating the representation, etc. My basic point is to not let the browser limitations wag your REST API, you can use a separate facade and let the browser influence that.

And this is a logical separation, whether that's manifested in the URL patterns, I have no opinion. That's more a development/maintenance/deployment call. I find that logical separations that can be manifested physically has some benefits in terms of clarity and understanding, but that's me.

Doug -

The raw HTML user experience is a crummy one. If it weren't, there wouldn't be an entire industry surrounding making the browser user application experience un-crummy. Of course it can be functional, and using HTML is an excellent media type for REST applications BECAUSE of the tooling around browsers and such that make working with the interface, viewing artifacts, interacting with the service when possible easier to do. But you don't design your service API around your debugger, and the raw browser is an incomplete tool for fully exploiting HTTP. As a host for JS through XHR, it gets more capable, but now we're talking "rich client" rather than just straight HTML in a browser.

While you can make service POST facades for delete et al, as in your example, the only reason you ARE doing that is because of the limitations of the browser, not for the sake of the API itself. If anything it's cluttering and complicating the API. "More than one way to do it."

Now, obviously you can tunnel everything through POST, simply because you like to tunnel everything through POST. But by hiding things this way you bypass other aspects of the protocol. If you POST foo/1 to /deleteFoos, you won't be able to leverage things like caches and such. A DELETE on foo/1 would invalidate any caches that see the operation, but a POST would slip right through, leaving the old, now deleted, resource behind.

So, there's reasons why there are other verbs than POST and GET in the protocol, even if the native browser chooses not to use them.

Comment: Thanks Will.  It might be that the browser is not a particularly good REST client, but I don't see your argument 'you shouldn't limit your API to its weak capabilities' The web service REST API should provide the functionality required, GET, POST, PUT, DELETE for resources.  The GETs to the Urls used for those resources could serve up a client specific representation (some clients want JSON some want XML, browsers want HTML) and I don't really see why there should be a separate URL for the browser to use to get the view of the resource, ctnd...

Comment: or why there should be specific Urls for the browser to DELETE resources from the server or POST new resources.  And I don't see why the browser would be driving the API.  There might be additional URLs for the website, like the home page (which might not have a similar concept from an API point of view), but this would be in addition to the REST API, not forcing the shape of the API would it?  Not every URL would need to be implemented in the API just because the website used it would it?

Comment: There is nothing wrong or inherently unRESTful with having a resource foo/1 support DELETE but also having a trash resource that lets you POST the URI foo/1 and delete it there. In the later, the HTML form would be a simple "Delete" submit button with an action="foo/trash" or whatever. Stop thinking about URIs and think about relationships.

Comment: And I don't see why a pure HTML RESTful app is "crummy". It might not be as seamless - but again, that is backwards compatible. A perfectly engineered web application would have JavaScript that "turns on" the Web 2.0 bells and whistles and offers a rich experience. If you need anything else other than JavaScript+CSS to "prettify" your web (page) interface, you've got an obvious coupling of client and server there. I'm not suggesting that vanilla HTML makes a great experience. I'm suggesting it's a useful constraint for getting yourself to think REST. You add the richness after. It's icing.

Comment: Lastly, for all the bad rap a browser gets for only supporting GET/POST, how many of you actually expose a resource that is truly idempotent in terms of PUT/DELETE? Do you even really DELETE things, or do you flag them as inactive (and still response to GET with a non-404 response)?

Comment: "If anything it's cluttering and complicating the API."

That's a bit of a stretch. I agree, the browser experience sans JavaScript leaves room for great improvement, and your comment about there being an industry around it is valid. My point is that aspiring to be RESTful is itself aspiring to be constrainted, and the browser provides what I feel is a good basis for being constrainted, for thinking about things in terms of those constraints, to provide getting ahead of yourself. Your "API" is XML/JSON and you don't mention those POST facades. No one is going to invoke them by accident.

Comment: @Doug Actually I think there is a lot unRESTful about having a POST which actually deletes (caching etc as Will touched on) and this is only done in browsers because of the lack of support for the other HTTP verbs than GET/POST.  This is exactly what I want to try and avoid and would like to have resources which support the 4 main verbs, and not have to have 'hacks' like DELETE/PUT via POST in the browser.  This seems possible if javascript is enabled, but not so much if not.  I'm leaning towards the website as first client of the API approach and dog fooding my API.

Comment: I'm suggesting that. I'm also saying that if you want, you can get a non-JS version working. Can you explain how DELETE vis POST (again, I ask if you're *really* DELETEing a resource or just POSTing an inactive flag to it) is not RESTful? State transfer is perfectly represented.

Comment: @Doug first, assume I am *really* deleting things.  2nd its not restful, as the intent is not visible to the intermediaries, so intermediate caches can't be invalidated and the intermediaries might still return a cached version when GET requests for that resource are recieved.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is reasonble of you to require javascript to allow you to utilize ajax techniques to do what you suggested in the third paragraph of your question.

Also, to clarify, no matter the client use the Location header of the 201 response to indicate the canonical URI of the newly created resource. These can be checked by your javascript, for clients that use it.

About 'dumber' clients (like: a browser with js disabled), a somewhat ugly way to have them do the redirect is to have a html meta refresh in the returned resource's html representation head section from the POST. The body of the response can then just briefly describe your new resource so long as you use the Location header.