# Create an API within existing web application or separate?

Tags: java, spring, api, rest, jpa

I've read through a few questions related to this topic ( [Jersey REST API as a separate web app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9647951/jersey-rest-api-as-a-separate-web-app), [Should web service be separate from web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8157617/should-web-service-be-separate-from-web-site)), but I still struggle to understand which design practice would work best for an existing application.

I inherited a java web application built on spring and hibernate JPA. It's currently in production with new features being developed.

Concurrently, I will need to design a REST API that will have some form of authentication/user tracking. The web application has its own user authentication system that is likely going to be different than the API implementation (i.e. username/pw vs api keys (?)).

Given this situation, I think it'd be best to develop them separately, but I feel like in the beginning, there will be a lot of code duplication (as a result of all the jpa implementation in the web application). Ideally, once I have the rest api in place, I would switch the web application to use the API as well and remove most of the backend code that currently handles the data retrieval.

Before I start down this route though, I was wondering, is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

you can use Spring Security and create a custom AuthenticationProvider . You can use a JNDI lookup to get the authservice directly from the Container it self.

Example:

```
@Component
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider {
     @Autowired
     private AuthService authService; 

public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) 
  throws AuthenticationException {
    String name = authentication.getName();
    String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();

    // use the credentials to try to authenticate against the third party system
    if (authService(name, password)) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuths = new ArrayList<>();
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(name, password, grantedAuths);
    } else {
        throw new AuthenticationException("Unable to auth against third party systems");
    }
}

@Override
public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
    return authentication.equals(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class);
}
```

Also, read more about RESTful apis using Spring here:

http://www.baeldung.com/rest-with-spring-series/

Comment: my main concern about adding spring security on top of my existing application is compatibility with the existing authentication system in place...or massive changes required to make it work.

Comment: What's the architecture of the existing authentication system?

Comment: custom, as far as I can tell. a couple controllers handle a user's session, making calls to the backend as needed to log a user in and determine the user's permissions (which impacts the screens a user sees)

Comment: I'm not sure if i understand all the context of the problem. You have a legacy application which run on it's own authentication service, and you need to build a different service as a RESTful API and you need to authenticate both, right?  If that's the problem you could find a way to authenticate the RESTful web service, via your existing web application service. If you need to authenticate both, you could write an API who does the authentication and implement it in the web api and on the RESTful service.

Comment: I wouldn't call it a legacy application, as it will still need to function/run while/after the api is being built. I need to create a Secure REST API (thinking of using api keys or something along those lines; still researching that aspect). The application currently does use REST (mostly, but not completely) for handling data requests, but it's not completely locked down. Most of the authentication that occurs for the application is via a user login. I suspect that it will be difficult to maintain and secure the existing REST services within the web app, hence the question.